# How could a supreme god give patch notes to reality?

Tags: gods, death, knowledge

A supreme god has decided that reality has some serious faults. Supply lines are moving too slowly, technology has stagnated, and disasters threaten the planet's future structure. As such, they intend to introduce several patches to reality updating humans, the way biology and physics works, and lots of stuff.

They want to inform humans of this so that they can be prepared, offer respecs to people whose current builds might be negatively impacted by the patch. They also don't want to cause widespread panic or devastation or damage to society from things like having patch notes pop up in front of drivers so that they crash their cars.

How can they best give people patch notes without causing widespread disruption and death?

Comment: Given how easily changing any meaningful-to-us part of physics or basic chemistry break things, your best bet you could make would be to change DNA or add new magic materials, but even then... Major changes and additions always create a readaptation time, aka disruptions.

Comment: In any case, do you ask about how to inform people or what minimal and less game-breaking changes you can make?

Comment: They have enough power to ensure the laws of physics remain functional, just not enough to predict in an absolute way how humans will react and how free will will evolve and such. Disruption and adaption is expected.

Comment: Just update your Minecraft already, and quit pretending that there's no log4j exploit bug. Jeez.

Comment: Obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/1172/

Comment: Are news channels and websites a thing in your world? Why not send a daily message for 6 months leading up to the patch implementation?

Comment: It's earth basically, so yes.

Comment: make some faces on Mars, some people are very good at reading faces they read minds...

Comment: What are the limits of your supreme gods power? Just introduce the patches and update everyone's consciousness and memories so that they just *know* what's going to change and when.

Comment: A great piece of fiction that renders this plot device well: _Unsong_ by Scott Alexander.

Comment: "having patch notes pop up in front of drivers so that they crash their cars" - I can't imagine a god would have much trouble displaying a message for every individual at a time when it's safe (e.g. the moment they wake up), or just taking control of their bodies for a few moments (or freezing time itself) until they've processed the message and they're fully aware of the real world again.

Comment: Retroactive memory editing is certainly possible, but they would prefer not to forcibly violate the minds of people, and they don't have good predictions of what would happen if everyone's memories and minds changed vastly.

Comment: How big are your patch notes?  Can you fit them into 10 points, and onto two stone tablets ?

Comment: Fairly long and extensive, and they also want to offer individual messages to people. Like say, if they eliminate truck driving as a profession they might offer to respect their truck skills into something else.

Comment: Would the supreme god even need patch notes? Can't he patch reality such that we already know what the changes are?

Comment: They could do lots of different things, infinite power means a lot of options.

Comment: There is a youtube channel dedicated to this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hNb0sD7bD8

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This isn't something that you can leave up to proxies that some might call 'prophets'.  Prophets, especially in this day and age of higher education, are often seen as being unreliable charlatans, and people are more inclined to believe what they can experience for themselves.

So, with that in mind, you need to notify *everyone* with the wit to understand the message... but how to do it?

The safest way would be to pass on the message in people's dreams.  While dreaming, people are typically in a safe place, unlikely to have an accident (other than one that they might have been prone to *because* they were sleeping) because a message from the upgrade team popped into their minds.

If the upgrade notice and patch details were transmitted to its recipients in a way that they would be remembered as if they were a long-term memory and not a mere ephemeral dream to be forgotten soon after waking, the fact that *everyone* has had an identical, unforgettable dream with the exact same content should be sufficient to convince even the greatest sceptics that something out of the ordinary has happened, and that the content of the shared dream is something that should be given serious consideration.

If the dream predicts some rare but unmistakable event, such as the supernova of a nearby (but not *too* nearby) star at a particular place and time, then that waking corroboration would put the message beyond any doubt, and at that point, anyone who chose to ignore its message wouldn't be able to claim afterwards that they didn't know or weren't told.

You might not be able to get 100% of people to pay attention, but you can at least make those who are ignoring the matter have to *work* at ignoring it.

Comment: "You might not be able to get 100% of people to pay attention, but you can at least make those who are ignoring the matter have to work at ignoring it." - Well now I'm imagining people trying to "Remind Me Later"-ify their dreams.

Comment: As an aside, this reminds me of the plot of FlashForward (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FlashForward); every* person on Earth blacks out for 2m17s and has a vision of their lives 6 months in the future.

Comment: Sidenote: Most people don't actually like pushy patch notes.  They actually want to be able to ignore it and just deal with the differences when they come.

Comment: @Nosajimiki True... but the OP noted that as a result of this patch, the users would be given the opportunity to "change their build", i.e. there is potentially user action required.  That would require that everyone pay attention, or suffer the consequences.

Comment: This sounds similar to the Fatima Prophecy/Miracle of the Sun of 1917 and The Fatima Storm of 1938.

Answer (score 24):

### We already have the patch notes... we just don't call them that.

The whole Bible is just a bunch of user documentation and patch notes told in a narrative format.  In the Old Testament, God describes all the things humans needed to do to work with Natural Law 1.0.  All of the "Laws" of the Old Testament were in fact instructions on how use the world before the 1.1 update.  No body knew about Chemistry back then because it did not exist, just a bunch of hard-coded cause and effects.  You drink water, you stop being thirsty, you rub two sticks together, you make a fire, you sacrifice your first born goat, and the rest of your goats will be bigger.

Then you hit Isaiah, and the tone of the Bible changes.  It stops being so much a user manual and starts being filled with all these prophesies about how God will change the world.  Then somewhere around 5BCE, God released a local version of his patch in the area surrounding Jerusalem.  As the laws of nature changed, all sorts of bugs happened.  Some people went blind, some went lame, some died unnatural deaths, some became demonically possessed, etc.  So he went around fixing the bugs and repairing the damage.  Once the bugs were all resolved, and everything was made backwards compatible, he pushed the update to the whole world, and we are all now running Natural Law 1.1.38.

It was a pretty cool patch really, now we have chemistry and physics and stuff so that we can now mix and match things to create our own new cause and effects... although it would have been really nice if they would have kept the blood sacrifice stuff, but it turned out that system had some pretty nasty exploits.

Thereafter, the beginning of the New Testament serves us as the revised user manual telling us what features were depreciated and what features are new ... but ever since the current version was released, he's been working on a much bigger update: Natural Law 2.0.  This is where the book of Revelations comes in.  This one he expects to have some pretty major consequences so he warns us about the plagues, famines, wars, and death etc, but he also informs us of his plans to backup user accounts (the rapture) and restore them when all is said and done (the resurrection) with new bodies and a new world map.  He's also warned us that a lot of user accounts will be getting banned after the Natural Law 2.0 update since better user account moderation seems to be one of the big key points of the new system. Since this next patch is coming with a world wipe, there is not really anything to prepare for... though it is highly recommended that you follow the current terms of service to make sure you don't get banned after the new moderation tools are in place.

*... for a less Christian biased version of this answer, just replace the Bible with whatever "holy texts" would be appropriate for your setting, and just have those texts already follow the theme of documentation/patch notes cycles. If you use ficticous holy books, you can in fact have a much more clear development cycle documented.*

### Why use something as unreliable as holy texts?

Because the god wants you to go about your normal life.  Any god that needs to patch reality is admitting that he messed up something in the first place.  Sure, he COULD come to everyone in a dream and explain everything he did wrong and what he needs to do to fix it, but the sudden confirmation that we are all at the mercy of a god AND that that god is fallible could have devastating consequences on society.  Atheists and religious persons alike would have their entire identities shaken to the core.  All the things we tell ourselves that help us cope with the daily stresses of life would suddenly be kicked out from under us resulting in a global case of mass hysteria.  I mean, last time he tried confirming his existence to tell us about a patch he was doing, he got nailed to a cross...so, maybe full disclosure is not the best of polices.

No, he needs to release patch notes to cover his own arse, but he also needs to maintain order.  So instead of announcing in an unmistakable manner "Here everyone is exactly everything that I got wrong!" the god in question can use holy texts and human intermediaries so that when things don't work out that god can just blame those silly humans who did not write it down properly, or maybe they did not listen right, or maybe it was a translation error... and for those who don't read the bible, even better! The “[But the plans were on display…](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/40705-but-the-plans-were-on-display-on-display-i-eventually)” excuse is a handy way to cover your butt without exposing yourself.

Comment: Amusingly, people clinging to Natural Law 1.0 also makes sense considering all the people who prefer older versions of software/games.

Comment: Continuing in this style, there exist user forums where people discussed the various versions and patches of Natural Law, submitted bug reports, and compared their understandings of the user manual.  One forum (no longer being updated) is archived as the Talmud.

Comment: Outstanding answer!  Reminds me of a televised panel I once watched with leading scientists discussing the possibility that we might actually be part of a simulation run by a higher being.  Oh, but when the word “God” came up it was tragi-comic to see their nervous avoidance techniques.  Not getting preachy here, just sayin’…

Comment: Always read the instruction manual: If all else fails you may want to wipe the hard disk and re-init world. Note that this is a lengthy process and may take longer than the first install. Before doing so it is strongly recommended to make a backup ark-ive of a male and a female sample of every animal species.

Comment: The Bible was written by humans (regardless of whether you believe it was divinely inspired) and plenty of people doubt it as a source of truth (and quite a few are probably barely or not at all aware of it). So... probably not the best idea to go with exactly that if you want everyone to know about it and believe it. Also, I can't tell how serious you're being in this answer, but if I take it literally, then you're giving the Bible waaaaaaaay too much credit for helping humanity improve their understanding of the natural world (most/all of that was known long before the Bible came along).

Comment: @NotThatGuy How many people open a product, see the instruction manual right there on top, throw it aside and choose to do their own thing instead?  Many people will not take the Bible or other sacred texts seriously, just like they do not take instruction manuals, or patch notes seriously... that is precisely what makes it such a good analogue.  Instead of the god in this setting MAKING SURE EVERYONE KNOWS, it is more likely he will just do his due diligence to make sure everyone can know who cares enough to read, because more intrusive patch notes than that are not generally appreciated.

Comment: Since the system isn't letting me award the bounty immediately (never mind that I explicitly clicked the little button saying that I wanted to reward an existing answer), I wish it to be known that the bounty I've put on this question is for you.

Comment: @Nosajimiki We've had plenty of failed predictions about events on certain days/weeks/months/years, and quite a few of those were based on the Bible. Telling a small group of random people about it and hoping they tell everyone else, without any compelling evidence to convince them with, might've proven to be effective at reaching quite a few people, but it's also proven to be ineffective at reaching/convincing everyone "who cares enough to read". My issue is not "plenty of people won't care", my issue is "almost no-one will have good reason to believe it's true, and plenty will never see it".

Comment: Now if a few billion religion texts were to suddenly appear out of thin air all over the world, then that would be some good evidence to actually believe what's written in it, but the convincing part would not be their existence, but rather that they appeared out of thin air.

Comment: @NotThatGuy What, you've never seen a release date missed? or an update pushed that turns out to be quite different than promised?  If the god in this setting were infallible, there would be no need for patch notes.  But, when a creator is fallible, it is best to be a bit vague about your future promises, because you never know what will go wrong during development that will force you to change your plans.

Answer (score 15):

### The Sky

> Hey, that comet wasn't there before! Wait, it's forming Markdown code? Oh, look at the top! A filename! README.md!

Scientists and laymen alike look at the sky on a daily basis. Just stick some large, hard-to-miss message in the sky, and teach the peoples of Earth all they need to know. You'll have to make it change languages depending on whos looking at it, but that's trivial for a god.

### Dreams

> It is I, your mighty God. I've come to show you the release notes for The Universe, v1.2. Here they are!
> • Deleted pain
> • Upgraded driver for the SENTIENCE system
> • Fixed bug that caused computer to overheat when spacebar was held down

A lot of people have covered this already, but yeah. Tell something to someone while sleeping. Some people might ignore it, but not everyone, and when everyone in the world has the same dream, things might get a little more (or less) believable.

### Thought Delivery

Now, a supreme god could do something physical, or dreams. Or he could just make everyone believe one thing. "Reality now works this way". Boring, sure, but effective.

### Food for Thought

> Yay! Our pizza arrived! Hey, there's a message on the box! "PATCH NOTES FOR THE UNIVERSE v1.2"

Everyone eats. Set it up so that all food has a message inside of it, weather it's a message on a pizza box, a paper inside a fortune cookie, or a change of the nutrition facts on a box of cereal.

### Probability is for losers

> "Don't knock over the milk, chil—", "Aw... come on. Seriously!" "Hey, daddy , look at the words in the milk!" PATCH NOTES FOR THE UNIVERSE VERSION 1.2

Make it so that it's incredibly likely that anything that happens will result in a message showing. Like, you drop milk and it forms words. Or a wall cracks and the cracks form words. You get the idea.

Comment: That last idea has Bad Wolf vibes, I like it!

Comment: I find it very comedic (in a good way!) that the supreme god communicates in Github-flavored Markdown, titled README.md, somewhere in the constellations. It can be interpreted as the god's subtle hint to inform humanity "the world is a simulation, this message is informing you of a bugfix patch recently implemented, just like *your* human software." **Universe is a simulation, confirmed.**

Comment: *"Upgraded driver for the SENTIENCE system"*. Or if we're unlucky, `FIXED: CVE-4500000000-005 "nondeterministic behavior in some mammals" (aka the "sentience" bug)`

Comment: "message in the sky" -> "message**s** in the sky ... all over the world, in whatever the local language is if you want to limit the number of things that might be non-trivial to explain with hard science, like having the same object be perceived differently for different people based on the language they speak"

Comment: I don't want to be that pedant, but it's Markdown, not Markup. And I would hope we're seeing the rendered version of the Markdown and not the source itself :P

Comment: @user You're right. Fixing that now.

Comment: Although, the Markdown source isn't that unreadable

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1172/)

Comment: @Firedestroyer True, unless you have a table with lots of columns and you don't make the `|`'s line up nicely, which will probably the case with these patch notes, given how many laws the god is changing (and since the god is a god, they probably don't realize we humans can't interpret Markdown tables unless formatted nicely)

Comment: @TheDaleks Finally, someone noticed!

Answer (score 13):

*Blink*

Just a moment ago, I had been driving down I-4pi, getting annoyed at the guy cutting me off only 50 feet from my exit. And now I was standing in a pure white.... nothingness. Nothing was underneath me, yet I was standing without falling. Nothing above me, yet there was light enough to see whatever there was to see.

And what there was to see was people.

And endless horde of people, stretching around me, before me, and behind me as far as the eye could see. Even as the image registered in my brain, the person in front of me took a step forward, and I did likewise without thinking.

"Oh, hey, it's you."

I looked around for the source of the voice. In the queue next to me, I recognized the guy who had just cut me off.

"Sorry about that," he said. "I think we were both trying to get to the same exit, and - well, I've been trying to get over for the last half mile, but you're the first person to give me anything resembling an opportunity."

I forced a noncommittal smile onto my face. "Yeah, I've been having the same problem." The queue advanced again, and I went with it. "I've been having a rough day, what with the kids not letting me get out the door. I don't think I'm going to make it to my interview on...." I trailed off, not sure how whatever *this* was was going to affect my drive time.

The guy grimaced like he had just bit off a chunk of the white nothingness and discovered that it was definitely not marshmallows. "So, uh, what do you think this is all about?"

I shrugged. "I don't know. I almost feel like I should be freaking out about this, but for some reason.... I'm just not. Like whatever this is, it's okay." A few murmured agreements sounded around us as the line moved forward again.

Our conversation continued as the line slowly advanced. I have no idea how long it took; it could have as easily been years as minutes. But suddenly I found myself at the front of the line, where a series of white tableclothed folding tables stretched off to the right and left as far as I could see. Behind the tables were a number of winged beings with bored looks on their faces.

"Next, please," the guy across from me intoned. I crossed the gap to stand across the table from him.

"Please sign here for your receipt of Form PN-1.1, notes on the upcoming systems patch of reality."

"I, uh-" I looked around. I didn't see any notes, only the paper he wanted me to sign.

"Sign here, please," he repeated, tapping the suddenly highlighted, underlined space with a pen that I was sure he wasn't holding a moment ago. I was halfway through signing before it occurred to me to demand to see the form I was signing for; and the moment it did occur to me, my brain was filled with a chaotic mess of data that mostly didn't apply to me personally, but I could almost swear I sensed some underlying purpose to it all.

And then it was gone, I was done signing, and the winged man was shoving another paper at me. He didn't bother explaining this one to me, as the rapidly evaporating release notes left me with some instructions on selecting compensation for the inconvenience of the upgrade process. I hurriedly selected a charisma and rapport boost to help me with my interview, and then suddenly--

*Blink*

My anger unexpectedly dissipated as I watched the guy who had just cut me off continue down the exit in front of me. I was sure he had his own life and problems, and -- My anger unexpectedly dissipated as I watched the guy who had just cut me off continue down the exit in front of me. I was sure he -- *Whoah. Deja vu.* I shook my head in confusion. *Did something just happen?* No, surely that weird hiccup in my perception of time had something to do with the feeling that my brain was shrinking, until it was once more small enough to fit inside my head.

*Weird, I don't remember taking any drugs last night.*

It ultimately turned out that not only was the guy who cut me off going to the same place as me, he was actually my interviewer. Normally this would have thrown me off my game, but for the first time in just about forever, I felt like I could handle talking to people. Also, I could swear that I saw the same odd feeling of familiarity on his face that I felt myself.

I ended up getting the job, but given how the rest of the world suddenly seemed to be on the upswing as well, I probably would have been fine without it. But I'm not the only one who had the weirdest feelings out of nowhere that day.

Comment: It reminds me of the situations on Terry Pratchet's Discworld novels. A sobrenatural situation is carried entirely as if it was a mundane everyday process, with the usual burocratic steps. Only everything is speed up because it uses magic.  They make the same in The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy, using science so advanced that is indistinguishable from magic from the point of view of the protagonist. Those novels are very good inspiration for this sort of scenes.

Comment: Dang - its like a short story right there !

Comment: Great answer! I really like the story aspect

Answer (score 6):

Select some key users and invest them of the role of "prophets". They will spread the word that "the change" is coming, while giving detailed descriptions of what "the change" will entail.

Make it with enough notice, so that the word can spread, and the "prophets" can gain some early adopters to help.

Maybe you can also release a limited beta in a test environment, calling it "miracles", just to be sure that your Agile WOW hasn't screwed things up. You still remember the BSOD at the presentation of Windows, right?

Comment: Why will people believe the prophets? This approach hasn't given us universal acceptance of any allegedly-divinely-inspired religious text to date.

Answer (score 6):

#### Invent brane collisions, then give humanity the means to detect them, then throw a brane at them and let them figure it out.

(Also, drop some hints that it's happened before.)

One of the foundational principles of modern science is that the rules of reality don't suddenly *change* for no reason.  Unless there is a specific reason to believe otherwise, anything that is happening now is assumed to have always been happening, and anything that happened in the past is expected to continue happening.

If something changes (there are humans now when there weren't before, technology advances, stars and planets formed, the universe came into existence) it is only because it was caused by a more primordial, less changeable law (evolution, thermodynamics, quantum fluctuations).

Throw away this principle, and you basically throw away all of science. How can we guess what happened in the past based on the present, or make plans for the future, if there is no foundational rule that isn't suddenly going to change for no reason?

Since the question asks for an answer that will not cause widespread disruption, you definitely don't want to resort to mass revelation, prophets, or a sudden change with no explainable natural cause. This would reveal the presence of the supreme god *and* make people less confident in science's ability to predict the future. Major disruption.

So you invent a more fundamental law that you pretend is the "real" cause for the changes, put hints for these changes happening in the past, and set them up in just such a way that scientists can plausibly explain why they didn't notice before.

One mechanism that can do a lot of heavy lifting and work with a modern understanding of physics: create evidence for "brane collision events" where collisions with parallel universes (that you just invented) can suddenly alter certain cosmological constants. This has been part of speculative physics for a while, although there isn't any evidence for it actually happening...yet.

Use subtle, subconscious revelations to guide scientists to create a device that can detect nearby branes, and plant a few clues in the fossil record that can be understood as brane collisions that happened millions of years ago (or better yet, put some clues in relatively recent history - like, once every few centuries - so they think that these collisions have already been happening fairly regularly without destroying human civilization, and therefore don't immediately panic).

Then you can just let scientists figure out on their own that these events happen - and that there's a brane heading right for us. Also give them a way of predicting the new rules of that brane, so that it doesn't cause undue panic and they can prepare for the change (and update technology so that it still works with the new rules). With any luck, you can get away with the update and cause no more disruption than the Y2K bug - in addition to creating a mechanism that will allow you to apply more updates in the future.

Comment: I like this idea as a way of explaining some of it, though I do also want some sort of patch notes.

Answer (score 5):

Advance warning.   Do unrelated things first.  Make them very nice things,  without putting people under control, because while some people will still suspect that the nicer they are, the worse they are being gulled, bad things will make everyone suspicious.

Though it may be well to make some of them stern.  Forcibly detoxifying drug addicts and marvelously preventing them from getting high ever again may convey the message that not listening may have unpleasant consequences.

To provide explanations that people will understand, use words.  Instead of hijacking electronics, change printed words, such as signs.  Illiterate people will need verbal messages.   Sea shells and other hollow objects that can not speak, perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

Ok so your gods are going to intervene sticking little (yellow ??) patch notes on windows and doors..

**500 years ago it worked**

It could work, when religious directions can solve the issues. Maarten Luther stuck 95 theses on paper, on a church door in 1517, which changed a quite lot in modern Christianity.

But what Luther did was only a reminder to the church, rather than humanity in general. As I understand your question, these "patch notes" should solve issues in real life and improve society. Belief systems are not good at that, they mostly fight symptoms rather than providing real life templates that solve problems.

**.. modern humans prefer to solve their issues without intervention**

Since technology advanced and magic declined, "gods" and "humans" diverged and the gods became impopular, or viewed upon as primitive. Lots of humans would choose a path 180 degrees different from a god's advice, just to show they don't believe in gods. These little patch notes come from the government, in their view.

**Subliminal patch notes**

A modern god would probably choose some secret method for this: to whisper the patch note words in our ears, while we sleep.. or mix in subliminal messages on certain websites. The human would wake up, or "invent" a solution and leave the gods out of it. Humans are soo difficult to manage !

Comment: The change wreaked by Martin Luther is especially notable given the fact that he wasn't actually trying to really change anything; the 95 theses were literally "Hey, I'm not quite sure about these bits of doctrine, so I'm going to host a debate to get these issues figured out." The actual change happened when the Church overreacted by sending the Inquisition after him.

Answer (score 3):

## Dreaming

Sometimes you dream. Sometimes you have the great spirit of innovation, understanding more.

God intervenes. Everyone that goes to sleep has a dream, explaining what needs to be explained. Afterwards they just *know*. Anyone not falling asleep in these weeks will have microsleeps, still gaining the knowledge.

The advantage of dreaming is that they can apply to anything. A concept or idea, a smell or feeling. Anything within the understanding of humans and a bit outside. On addition, the person started sleeping, giving away conscious control. So the god isn't making it more dangerous than the himan who started sleeping.

If anyone doubts it the truth of it will be seen as soon as the rules change. Things work differently and this is most likely noticeable. Humans 2.0. Eyelashes don't randomly fall into the eye. You don't enter a room and instantly forget what you were doing. Calculus is finally easy.

Comment: “Anyone not falling asleep in these weeks will have microsleeps, still gaining the knowledge.” Most likely, they'll be too dead to notice. (To my knowledge,) nobody's spent more than three consecutive weeks awake, excepting those with severe brain damage rendering sleep impossible (and those people didn't survive much longer).

Answer (score 3):

Everyone "just knows".

People believe they always knew (or at least, have known for a long time). It's not news. No shock. No trust required - everyone knows it for a fact. People would be surprised that it's not actually written down, but then everyone knows, so it's not particularly important.

Answer (score 0):

It's in my head.
It's in your head.
It's in everyone's head.
It's like a shared conspiracy theory but nobody is complaining.
We all know it's happening.
We all KNOW it's logical that things happen this way.
We all seem to recall that this is always how change occurred, but we can't think when it last did - but we don't care.

It's not really CHANGE after all.
It's just reality again/still.
Business as usual.
Tomorrow and today are just the same but different.
Just different but the same.

Y'All take the Red pill AND the Blue pill together NOW but there are no actual pills and they take themselves itself and nothing will ever be the same again and you wake up tomorrow morning and nothing has changed.

Comment: Take the blue pill and you will forget about the patch and continue your life and will think the changes were always there. Take the red pill and you will know the patch notes and will notice the change.